# How do you stop an await Task.Delay() when a game over screen is displayed? in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I use a separate timer class to end the game and display a score, but after a few seconds, the screen reverts back to the previous game with the same scores. This is due to the timers I have running out.

So how do I stop those timers when the game over screen is displayed?

I'm using a 'await Task.Delay(1000)' to change a number and change it back after a certain time. I also have a separate Timer class which executes a game over screen. The problem is when the timer class goes off and displays the screen, the 'await Task.Delay' timer hasn't finished and continues to run

My code is as follows:

```
using PetrolStationGame;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{


    internal class Program
    {
        internal static char[] arr = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }; // Arrays for each pump
        internal static int choice; //Dictates player choice

        internal static int flag = 0;

        internal static int CarsWaiting = 0;
        internal static int CarsServiced = 0;
        internal static int FuelLitresSold = 0;
        internal static decimal IncomeMade = 0;
        internal static int Fuel = 15;
        internal static decimal PetrolPrice = 2;
        internal static decimal Commission = 0;
        //internal static double CommissionRate = 0.1;
        //private static object timer;





        internal static void petrol()
        {

            EndGameTimer.endgametimer();
            //RefreshTimer.refreshtimer();
            var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

            do
            {
                PetrolStationGame(); //Loads petrol station pumps
                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                CarsWaitingTimer.carswaitingtimer();

                if (arr[choice] != 'B')
                {
                    ServeCar();

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The pump {0} is already being used", choice);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }

                if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(400);
                }


                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(400);
                }




            } while (flag != 1);

            PetrolStationGame();
            Console.Clear();

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Game Over");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Draw");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        internal static async void ServeCar()
        {
            var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

            {

                int tmp = choice;
                arr[tmp] = 'B';
                CarsServiced++;
                FuelLitresSold = Fuel + FuelLitresSold;
                IncomeMade = FuelLitresSold * PetrolPrice;

                Commission = IncomeMade / 100;
                await Task.Delay(15000); // Time delay
                arr[tmp] = (char)(tmp + 48);
                PetrolStationGame();
                Console.WriteLine("A pump has become free!");



            }
            tokenSource2.Cancel();
        }

        internal static void SpawnCar()
        {


            CarsWaiting++;

        }



        internal static void PetrolStationGame()
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Cars Serviced {0}", CarsServiced);
            Console.WriteLine("Litres of Fuel Sold {0}", FuelLitresSold);
            Console.WriteLine("Income made: £{0}", IncomeMade);
            Console.WriteLine("Commission: £{0}", Commission);
            Console.WriteLine("Cars Waiting {0}", CarsWaiting);
            Console.WriteLine("                ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}    {1}    {2}", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("                ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}    {1}    {2}", arr[4], arr[5], arr[6]);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("                ");
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}    {1}    {2}", arr[7], arr[8], arr[9]);
            Console.WriteLine("                ");

        }

        internal static async void GameOver()
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("GAME OVER!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Cars Serviced {0}", CarsServiced);
            Console.WriteLine("Litres of Fuel Sold {0}", FuelLitresSold);
            Console.WriteLine("Income made: £{0}", IncomeMade);
            Console.WriteLine("Commission Made: £{0}", Commission);
            Console.WriteLine("Cars Left Waiting {0}", CarsWaiting);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Game Will Close in 5 seconds");




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Timer.Stop`??? Could you be more clear about the problem you are running into?

Comment: I'm using a 'await Task.Delay(1000)' to change a number and change it back after a certain time. I also have a seperate Timer class which executes a game over screen. The problem is when the timer class goes off and displays the screen, the 'await Task.Delay' timer hasnt finished and continues to run,

Comment: fwiw, I wouldn't call that a "timer". Either way, can't you just check if the game is over after the delay? I mean, there is technically a race condition there, but where you appear to be at (in terms of program design, etc) it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: The other timer looks more like this: System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 12000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel tasks (including `Task.Delay`). There's a detailed description [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx).

From that article, you create the cancellation token like this:

```
var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;
```

You can then pass the token to `Task.Delay`. Make sure you can save these somewhere so you can use them to cancel the task.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to figure out how to put it into my code :P

Comment: Note that task cancellation is *cooperative*. In this case, `Task.Delay` will cooperate with you; but don't expect user tasks to do so :) Alternatively, just check the game end flag after you return from the delay

Comment: There is no `Cancel` method on `CancellationToken`

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the correction, I wasn't sitting in front of an IDE when I wrote this